# Present storyboard view controller from app delegate?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have a view controller subclass, `SignInViewController`, used for sign in that might be needed at any time. Rather than have every view controller in my app listen for the notification that sign in is needed, I'd rather have the app delegate do it.

But how do I trigger it from my app delegate?

Do I put the `SignInViewController` in my main storyboard? If so, how do I access my storyboard from my app delegate? Or is some other approach better?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can always reference to your app delegate through the UIApplication singleton. 
From there you can always get your root view controller. 
With your root view controller you can get a reference to the storyboard.

Once you have your story board all you do is instantiate an instance of the view controller you want.
Present it.

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
MainViewController *mvc = (MainViewController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;    
LoginViewController *lvc = [mvc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
[currentVC presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES];
```

There may be a more direct way of getting a reference to your storyboard but this will almost always get it for you.

Comment: This means reference what view controller you are currently working in, done by using the keyword "self" in place of "currentVC".

Comment: but he asked about presenting from the appDelegate "before" being into any viewcontroller i bet

Comment: No, I didn't. Knowing that I need sign-in is not the sort of decision I can make in the short time period that the iOS watchdog allows me to set up my UI. The bigger problem is *from any* view controller.

Comment: Problem with this answer is this instantiates a new view controller, it does not give you the view controller that may have already been instantiated by the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To show a view controller from anywhere (including the app delegate), I have used this code with success in iOS 8+ (I'm not sure about earlier compatibility). It will present from the modal view if there is one.

```
YOURAppDelegate *appDelegate =  (YOURAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UINavigationController *rootNavC = (UINavigationController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *topVC = rootNavC.topViewController;

UIViewController *myNewVC = [rootNavC.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:<YOUR STORYBOARD ID>];

if (topVC.presentedViewController)
{
    if ([topVC.presentedViewController class] == [UINavigationController class])
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [((UINavigationController*)topVC.presentedViewController) pushViewController:myNewVC
                                                                                animated:YES];
        });
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [topVC.presentedViewController.navigationController pushViewController:myNewVC
                                                                          animated:animated];
        });
    }
}
else
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [rootNavC pushViewController:myNewVC
                            animated:animated];
    });
}
```

I usually wrap this in a convenience method and pass in my instantiated view controller. To OP - you would create SignInViewController in the storyboard, assign it a unique storyboard ID, and then substitute that ID in the above code.